# Two divs clicked at the same time (css)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I have two divs:

`<div id="div1">Click here</div>
<div id="div2">Click here</div>`

Is there a way to stack them one upon the other so that when I click one I click both. Preferably with css.

Any solution is welcome.

Comment: I would create an event handler for both that calls the same function. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Either make both of them call the same function or simulate a click event for the other one. Unless this is for learning purposes only, making them call the same function is the only solution that makes sense imo

Comment: Read about absolute positioning and event propagation.

Comment: Depends what happens when you click them, by default nothing really happens apart from they get focus so when you say you want a css only solution, what do you want to happen when you click them?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot trigger events with css.
You can with js:

```
document.getElementById('div1').addEventListener('click', () => { // on click in div1
  document.getElementById('div2').click(); // make div2 clicked
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have them both call the same function when clicked.

```
document.getElementById('div1').addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
document.getElementById('div2').addEventListener('click', onClick, false);

function onClick() {
    // Do something.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your script file. Clicking is handled by JavaScript, not by CSS. Even if you place one element over the other, you will be unable to click both at once.

```
var x = document. getElementsByTagName("div");

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
     // Whatever you want to do
    });
}
```